# Magento 2 - How to apply OG Tag for all products

Tags: magento2.3.4, magento-ecg

I am update OG tag for home page,

app\design\frontend\Zero\mytheme\Magento_Theme\layout\default_head_blocks.xml

```
 <meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/DEFAULTIMAGE.png" />
 <meta name="og:title" content="Printing coop is a most famous Digital Printing certer"/>
 <meta name="og:description" content="Printing coop is a most famous Digital Printing certer in Montreal Canada.Professional Printer Services."/>
```

How to apply for my Category, Products,  and CMS Pages &  blocks?

Answer (score 0):

For instance take a look for Product OG in `.../vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_opengraph.xml`

You will find this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <attribute name="prefix" value="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# product: http://ogp.me/ns/product#" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="opengraph.general" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/opengraph/general.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Directory\Block\Currency" name="opengraph.currency" as="meta.currency" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/opengraph/currency.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

You can overwrite this template `Magento_Catalog::product/view/opengraph/general.phtml` in your theme

Template:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */
?>

<meta property="og:type" content="product" />
<meta property="og:title"
      content="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->stripTags($block->getProduct()->getName()) ?>" />
<meta property="og:image"
      content="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getImage($block->getProduct(), 'product_base_image')->getImageUrl()) ?>" />
<meta property="og:description"
      content="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->stripTags($block->getProduct()->getShortDescription()) ?>" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProduct()->getProductUrl()) ?>" />
<?php if ($priceAmount = $block->getProduct()->getPriceInfo()->getPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE)->getAmount()) :?>
    <meta property="product:price:amount" content="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($priceAmount) ?>"/>
    <?= $block->getChildHtml('meta.currency') ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

And for Categories etc.. you can use the product as an example you can add a template to `head.additional` block

Comment: Magento_Catalog::product/view/opengraph/general.phtml -->  what is the path? My current project path like app/design/frontend/Zero_theme/my_theme/Magento_Catalog/

Comment: To overwrite the file in your them it would be like: `app/design/frontend/Zero_theme/my_theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/opengraph/general.phtml`

Comment: I have couple of doubts, 1) After added the given script to general.phtml anything else still i need to do, i mean should i update into any xml file, can you pls help me with this 2) For category can you pls guide me.